# Top category missing from ordinal classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, ordinal-classification

I am trying to implement an ordinal classifier based on the sources below:

- original source: [Simple Trick to Train an Ordinal Regression with any Classifier](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-trick-to-train-an-ordinal-regression-with-any-classifier-6911183d2a3c)
- updated coding: [How to use ordinal classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486947/how-to-use-ordinal-classifier)

In my training dataset, I have 5 categories (usefulness level 1 - level 5). However, I only end up with level 1- level 4 usefulness in the prediction for the test dataset using the code above (the answer in [How to use ordinal classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486947/how-to-use-ordinal-classifier)). I have enough samples in both training (n=1,000) and test (n=15,000) datasets.

```
from sklearn.base import clone
import numpy as np

# Source:
# 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486947/how-to-use-ordinal-classifier
# 2. https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-trick-to-train-an-ordinal-regression-with-any-classifier-6911183d2a3c


class OrdinalClassifier():

    def __init__(self, clf):
    self.clf = clf
    self.clfs = {}

def fit(self, X, y):
    self.unique_class = np.sort(np.unique(y))
    if self.unique_class.shape[0] > 2:
        for i in range(self.unique_class.shape[0] - 1):
            # for each k - 1 ordinal value we fit a binary classification problem
            binary_y = (y > self.unique_class[i]).astype(np.uint8)
            clf = clone(self.clf)
            clf.fit(X, binary_y)
            self.clfs[i] = clf

def predict_proba(self, X):
    clfs_predict = {k: v.predict_proba(X) for k, v in self.clfs.items()}
    predicted = []
    for i, y in enumerate(self.unique_class):
        if i == 0:
            # V1 = 1 - Pr(y > V1)
            predicted.append(1 - clfs_predict[i][:, 1])
        elif y in clfs_predict:
            # Vi = Pr(y > Vi-1) - Pr(y > Vi)
            predicted.append(clfs_predict[i - 1][:, 1] - clfs_predict[i][:, 1])
        else:
            # Vk = Pr(y > Vk-1)
            predicted.append(clfs_predict[i - 1][:, 1])
    return np.vstack(predicted).T

def predict(self, X):
    return self.unique_class[np.argmax(self.predict_proba(X), axis=1)]

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
oc = OrdinalClassifier(knn)
oc.fit(X_train, y_train)
oc.predict(X_test)
```

[Stats for each class in the training dataset and the three prediction models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tPVZ.png)

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question; the most probable reason (excluding possible coding errors) is that your training set is quite imbalanced, with (very) few `level 5` samples.

Comment: I have a balanced sample for the training dataset. This should not be a problem. Also, when I took out the level 5's in the training dataset, then used the above code, the test dataset will only have level 1- 3, with level 4 missing.

Comment: Do the predictions on the training set manage any 5s?

Comment: Yes. 16.5% of the training set is 5s.

Comment: Is that 16.5% of the _predictions_, or actual labels? What's the percentage of the other (predictions or actual labels)?

Comment: I think with k-neighbors, this style of ordinal classification ought to be equivalent to unordered classification. Do you get the same behavior from, say, `LogisticRegression`?

Comment: The 16.5% of 5s are the actual labels in the training dataset. In the prediction, there is no 5. Just tried other classification models, like Logistic Regression and Random Forest -- problem solved! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to double-check: when I said predictions above I was referring to the predictions _on the training set_.  If _that_ produces no 5s, it's probably an implementation issue; otherwise, it's probably a data- and model-specific issue. // If I'm right about KNN working just like unordered classification, then you should still be getting predictions for the class 5... // Can you provide a sample dataset that reproduces the issue?  If other models are working, I wonder if KNN with `n_neighbors > 5` would also work?

Comment: It is possible that KNN (also RandomForest) is just not as good as LogisticRegression for the dataset. At the bottom of the question, I added the stats for each class in the training dataset (n=794) and the three prediction models (n=15,159). Unfortunately, I couldn't share this dataset. Just some background information about this dataset -- the predictors are bag-of-word models from customer feedback verbatim and the industry dummies; the outcome variables are based on manual coding of the usefulness of customer feedback.